# Chai assertions not executed inside JSDOM Env block

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, chai, jsdom

I've just started writing my front-end unit tests with [mocha](https://mochajs.org/), [chai](http://chaijs.com/api/bdd/) and [jsdom](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsdom). When I try to follow the tutorials based on those - I'm getting *passing* tests even when I *set them to fail*. Everything else is setup and works as expected `jQuery, setup.js, window` etc. The only issue is that my Assertions are not getting executed at all inside the jsdom env block.

This is my test:

```
var chai = require('chai'),
    expect = chai.expect,
    jsdom = require('jsdom'),
    fs = require('fs'),
    jquery = fs.readFileSync('./js/vendor/jquery-3.0.0.min.js', 'utf-8');

describe('UI DOM tests', function () {

  it('should fail', function () {
    // simple html
    var htmlFragment = fs.readFileSync('./test/runner.html');

    jsdom.env({
      html: htmlFragment,
      src: [jquery, '../node_modules/chai/chai.js'],
      done: function (err, window) {
        var $ = window.$;

        expect(true).eql(false); // nothing happens

        done();
      }
    });

    expect(true).eql(false); // assert fails as expected
  });
});
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

it seems you're missing the `done` argument in your `it`:

```
it('should fail', function (done) {
```

otherwise mocha will think your `it` is synchronous and finish before your jsdom env is created.

Comment: Thanks mate, this was the problem. I really wasted a lot of time debugging, but didn't considered that.